# No sé por qué nunca consigo representar lo que quiero en ggplot

Tags: r

Tengo una duda porque estoy intentando hacer un grafico y no sé por qué no me deja.
Os pongo en contexto todo lo que pueda a ver si sabéis lo que está pasando.

```
EMEAdf <- myquery %>% 
  filter(Region == "EMEA", Year == 2022)
ggplot(data = EMEAdf, aes(x = month(Month), y = Value, fill = Value))+
geom_bar() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, max(EMEAdf$Value)))
```

Si ejecuto sólo la primera línea del gráfico (antes de geom_bar) todo va bien, pero después de geom_bar me da este error:

> Error en `geom_bar()`:
> ¡! Problema al calcular stat.
> ℹ Se ha producido un error en la 1ª capa.
> Causado por error en `setup_params()`:
> ¡! `stat_count()` sólo debe tener una estética x o y.
> Ejecute `rlang::last_error()` para ver dónde se ha producido el error.

Si añado `geom_bar(stat = "identidad")` funciona. Creo que esto se debe a que el gráfico de barras está diseñado naturalmente para contar las observaciones en lugar de sumarlas, pero no estoy muy segura. Aún así sigo confundida porque obtengo un gráfico que no distingue entre los distintos valores que tengo en la columna value (los cuales son dos, diferentes kpis) y además me está haciendo una escala de color en las barras (degradado en el tono de la barra que diferencia mayor o menor valor), lo cual tampoco le he especificado que hiciera.

Los datos que pretendo mostrar en el gráfico son de tipo dbl

Me da la sensación de que al ser principiante tiene que ser un error tonto, en la estructura de los datos. Espero que podáis ayudarme.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola! Sale algo más al usar `rlang::last_error()`?

Answer (score 1):

El error ya te está diciendo algo:

> stat_count() sólo debe tener una estética x o y

que básicamente significa que `geom_bar()`, o más bien `stat_count()`, espera que "mapeamos" la estética `x` o `y`, pero no las dos juntas, que es lo que estás haciendo con `aes(x = month(Month), y = Value, fill = Value)`. Esto es una razón de diseño y que en la ayuda lo dice:

> geom_bar() uses stat_count() by default: it counts the number of cases
> at each x position

Es decir, por defecto la altura de la barra se calcula "contando" cada categoría, por lo cual no se requiere más que una dimensión, por que la otra surge del estadístico que se usa, en este caso `stat_count()`. Sin embargo, si quieres que la altura la determine un valor especifico, puedes hacer dos cosas:

1. establecer el estadístico de `geom_bar()` a `identity`:

   ```
   + geom_bar(stat='identity')
   ```
2. Usar directamente `geom_col()` que usa directamente las estéticas `x` e  `y`.

   ```
   + geom_col()
   ```